# Data loop printing in terminal killable by user input

Tags: java, concurrency, terminal

My task is to print the currency exchange rate table in the terminal and print the table with delay every minute. On the user input, I shall end looping and get back to the customs terminal menu. How to achieve this?

In general, I have an issue to figure out how to have a seamless user experience. I need to have user input in the terminal and still print the data every minute if there is no user action. And eventually, if user decides to kill the printing, how to kill the overall data printing loop at all?  -> runFlag = ????;

Is it actually the right way to do it?

I have tried several approaches, non have been unfortunately working.

Can anybody help me?

So far I have only following code. Custom method for printing exchange rates in the loop:

```java
private void printExchangeRateTable(final Map<String, Integer> storedExchangeRates){

    boolean runFlag = true;
    do {

        printExchangeRates(storedExchangeRates);

        println("Hit any key to stop loop");

        Thread threadDelayer = new Thread(new Delayer());
        Thread threadListeningUserInput = new Thread(new UserInputListener());

        threadDelayer.start();
        threadListeningUserInput.start();

        runFlag = ????;

    } while (runFlag);
}
```

Delayer object

```
final class Delayer implements Runnable {

    public static final long MILISECONDS = 1000L;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * MILISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

UserInputListener

```
class UserInputListener implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        val userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        if(userInput != null) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set up a repeated task using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), but here, it’s much easier to send the reading of the user input into a background task

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    CompletableFuture<String> userInput = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s::nextLine);
    while(!userInput.isDone()) {
        printData();
        try {
            userInput.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch(ExecutionException|InterruptedException ex) {} // handled after the loop
        catch(TimeoutException ex) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    String input = userInput.join();
    // handle input
}

private static void printData() {
    System.out.println("data");
}
```

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s::nextLine)` will submit the execution of `s.nextLine()` to a background task. Then, the loop will run until the background task has been finished, executing `printData()` every minute. This is achieved via `userInput.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` which will throw a `TimeoutException` if no result is available after the specified time. The `continue` is not necessary here, as the loop will continue anyway, but I made it explicit.

The other possible exceptions are handled intrinsically. Interruption should not occur, but by going into the next iteration, it may be used as a signal to refresh the printed data even before the time. When an `ExecutionException` occurred, the erroneous state will be reported when we get the actual user input in the `join()` statement after the loop anyway.

This loop could be incorporated into a bigger loop as well

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
for(boolean quit = false; !quit; ) {
    CompletableFuture<String> userInput = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s::nextLine);
    while(!userInput.isDone()) {
        printData();
        try {
            userInput.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch(ExecutionException|InterruptedException ex) {} // handled implicitly
        catch(TimeoutException ex) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    String input = userInput.join();
    // handle input
    if(input.equals("exit")) quit = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I am using your same logic for reading user input, but for printing I will use a timer (here scheduled to run every 1 sec but you can change that). It is easier to manage a timer and can be canceled from another thread.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread inputListener = new Thread(new UserInputListener());
    inputListener.start();
}

static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("some output");
    }
}

static class UserInputListener implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run()  {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
        timer.cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use `java.util.Timer`. It’s a pity that this thing still hasn’t marked deprecated. Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), e.g. [`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()), instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need two threads, but you don't have to create two - you can use the main thread for user input and at the beginning of the program start the other thread that will print the currency rates every minute.

Each thread will have an infinite (or flag-controlled) loop inside. However, rather than managing this yourself, I would recommend using `ScheduledExecutorService`, otherwise you are going to struggle to interrupt the thread.

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Example::printData, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

            if (userInput.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static void printData() {
        System.out.println("data");
    }

}
```

If there is no other user input to handle and it is used only to stop the background thread, you don't need the loop in this thread at all and you can simplify it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Example::printData, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.nextLine();
    executor.shutdown();
}
```